# Deleting Visible Cells After Filtering

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am not sure why my VBA code is not working:

So I've tried the code and it works great for CNHK

But as I've replicated the code downwards it stops working

So for TW onwards (I've only included TW) I keep getting this error message:

"Delete method of Range class failed"

for this portion of the code:

r.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

I'm not too sure why that is as the only part I adjust is the range in each.

```
Sub CNHK()

Dim oLo As ListObject
Dim r As Range
Set oLo = Sheets("Data").ListObjects("Table2")
Set r = oLo.AutoFilter.Range
oLo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
        Array("AUSTRALIA", "FUKUOKA", "INDIA", "INDONESIA", "LONDON", "MALAYSIA", "NAGOYA", _
        "NORTH AMERICA", "OSAKA", "PHILIPPINES", "SINGAPORE", "SOUTH AMERICA", "SOUTH KOREA" _
        , "TAIWAN", "THAILAND", "TOKYO", "VIETNAM"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

r.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
oLo.Range.AutoFilter

Sheets(Array("Dash Fwd", "Dash Bck")).Select
    Sheets("Dash Fwd").Activate
    Rows("40:75").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("110:459").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("635:1054").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Sheets("Dash Bck").Activate
    Rows("40:75").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("110:459").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("635:1054").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

Sheets("Dash Fwd").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="013054", DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=False, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows _
        :=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
        AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    Range("A1").Select

Sheets("Dash Bck").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="013054", DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=False, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows _
        :=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
        AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub

Sub TW()

Dim oLo As ListObject
Dim r As Range
Set oLo = Sheets("Data").ListObjects("Table2")
Set r = oLo.AutoFilter.Range
oLo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
        Array("AUSTRALIA", "FUKUOKA", "INDIA", "INDONESIA", "LONDON", "MALAYSIA", "NAGOYA", _
        "NORTH AMERICA", "OSAKA", "PHILIPPINES", "SINGAPORE", "SOUTH AMERICA", "SOUTH KOREA" _
        , "BEIJING", "THAILAND", "TOKYO", "VIETNAM", "CHENGDU", "GUANGZHOU", "HONG KONG", "SHANGHAI"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

r.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
oLo.Range.AutoFilter


Sheets(Array("Dash Fwd", "Dash Bck")).Select
    Sheets("Dash Fwd").Activate
    Rows("40:110").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("145:1055").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Sheets("Dash Bck").Activate
    Rows("40:110").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("145:1055").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

Sheets("Dash Fwd").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="013054", DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=False, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows _
        :=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
        AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    Range("A1").Select

Sheets("Dash Bck").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="013054", DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=False, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows _
        :=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
        AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to write `debug.print r.Address` in the line before the mistake. It will show you whether `r` exists at all and whether it has some address in the immediate window.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is that there is nothing filtered left. Try to embed the error code with the following condition:

```
If not r is Nothing then
    r.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
end if
```

Furthermore, to see whether this is the case, write `debug.print r.Address` in the line before the mistake. If it is not set, it should be an error as well. Otherwise, it will print the address in the immediate window.

Answer (score 0):

PLease replace this part

`r.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`

of your code with this

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
r.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

You don't need to invoke the SpecialCells before deleting, because the method Delete acts only on the visible rows.

Comment: Oh wow thanks, that does work. Any idea why when I use the previous code it does not work for some reason? I found this article:

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=39623

Not sure if there is a limit to using specialcells as stated in the article but it does make some sense in my file, in the CNHK module I am erasing a lot less content than my TW module

Comment: I believe it has something to do with tables and filters being sometimes buggy when manipulating with VBA.  http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=202791 Could you, please, mark this as answered?